# Error "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" occurs when I try to use function parametrs as list indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I try to use parameters of a function as a list indices, however I get

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not a tuple.

```
days=['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth', 'tenth', 'eleventh']

gifts=['and a patriage in a Pear tree', 'two Turtle Doves', 'three French Hens', 'four Calling Birds', 'five Gold Rings', 'six Geese-a-Laying', 'seven Swans-a-Swimming', 'eigth Maids-a-Milking', 'nine Ladies Dancing', 'ten Lords-a-Leaping', ' eleven Pipers Piping', 'twelve Drummers Drumming']

def recite( start_verse, end_verse):
    return ('On the '+days[start_verse+1] + ' day of Christmas my true love gave to me: '+ gifts[-1, end_verse])

print(recite(2,2))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Comment: Were you expecting a slice of the list? For that try `gifts[end_verse-1::-1]`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here `gifts[-1, end_verse]`.
You are using a tuple as an index.

You should use just an integer value instead. Maybe you meant one of these options:

```
gifts[-1 + end_verse]
gifts[end_verse - 1]
gifts[-1]
gifts[end_verse]
```

Comment: Isn't it clearer to write `end_verse-1` than`-1+end_verse`?

Comment: Yes. of course. It was only a option I wrote but it's way clearer to use end_verse - 1

Answer (score 1):

I think this `gifts[-1, end_verse]` is the problem. You can't have tuple as  a list index. Maybe you wanted `gifts[end_verse-1]` here?

```
days=['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth', 'tenth', 'eleventh']


gifts=['and a patriage in a Pear tree', 'two Turtle Doves', 'three French Hens', 'four Calling Birds', 'five Gold Rings', 'six Geese-a-Laying', 'seven Swans-a-Swimming', 'eigth Maids-a-Milking', 'nine Ladies Dancing', 'ten Lords-a-Leaping', ' eleven Pipers Piping', 'twelve Drummers Drumming']

def recite(start_verse, end_verse):
    return 'On the '+ str(days[start_verse+1]) + ' day of Christmas my true love gave to me: '+ str(gifts[end_verse-1])

print(recite(2,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement is incorrect in the recite function. The following code below is probably what you want. This is assuming that recite(1,1) is for the first day, recite(2,2) the second, and so on.

```
def recite(start_verse, end_verse):
   days=['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth', 'tenth', 'eleventh', 'twelfth']
   gifts=['and a patriage in a Pear tree', 'two Turtle Doves', 'three French Hens', 'four Calling Birds', 'five Gold Rings', 'six Geese-a-Laying', 'seven Swans-a-Swimming', 'eigth Maids-a-Milking', 'nine Ladies Dancing', 'ten Lords-a-Leaping', ' eleven Pipers Piping', 'twelve Drummers Drumming']
   return("On the " + days[start_verse-1] + " day of Christmas my true love gave to me: " + gifts[end_verse-1])
```